# What is the alternative of EfInMemory.CreateOptions for .NET Core 6.0 from package EfCore.TestSupport

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-6.0

I am upgrading my .NET projects from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6.0.

I was using [Efcore.TestSupport.EfInMemory](https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCore.TestSupport/releases/tag/V3.0.0) v3.2.0 as a database for my test, but now the current version of [Efcore.TestSupport](https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCore.TestSupport) v5.3.0 it is not supporting `EfInMemory` for .NET 6.0.

What is the alternative to

```
var options = EfInMemory.CreateOptions<ApplicationDbContext> ()
```

Full code:

```
using TestSupport.EfHelpers;
using Xunit;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [Fact]  
    public async Task GetData_WhenNotExist_ShouldReturnNull()
    {
        var options = EfInMemory.CreateOptions<ApplicationDbContext>(); // EfInMemory not available in `Efcore.TestSupport` v5.3.0 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Upgrade document](https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCore.TestSupport/blob/master/Version5UpgradeDocs.md) says (at the 6th item of the summery) `ef in memory` is removed and no longer supported.and as the document says:

> If you need it then use EF Core's In Memory database provider!

But the better option would be to use `SQLLite in memory` instead. Take a look at [here](https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCore.TestSupport/wiki/Using-SQLite-in-memory-databases)

Comment: but my production database isn't using a SQLite database

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft EF Core's In Memory database provider?

Comment: Using EF Core InMemory is [discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). If you are using SqlServer `SqlLite in memory` would be OK if you do not use some feature. Although you may encounter some difficulties but even in other testing tool developers are switching to `SQLLite InMemory` for testing. Take a look at [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)